# Is it incorrect to mix conditionals type 0 and 2

Tags: conditionals

to clarify the title what i refer to is:
if clause type 0: If I drink too much coffee, I can't sleep at night.
and type 2: If we had a garden, we could have a cat.
sentences are taken from [BC Web site](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/conditionals-1)

I was writing an essay for the IELTS and wrote this sentence:
If the government provides free education for these classes, children would gain access to them for free, regardless from their parents’s income.

So I consider a possible scenario here, nothing actually happens.

I know conditionals are all about ruleness-ness as once an experienced british private tutor told me in class.

But I don't know about if it is correct to mix them in formal english.

Comment: ruleness-ness? Do you mean: correctness or not of x?

Comment: *When*  the government provides free education for these classes, children gain access to them for free, regardless from their parents’s income. No *if* at all. Anyway, the tenses are the same, even with *if*.

Answer (score 0):

This mixture is (I think) fairly common in informal speech, but you would typically use the second conditional here, and say "provided" instead of "provides." This is correct even though the (hypothetical) providing is in the present or future.

Comment: Agreed. "Provided" makes sense because the condition is hypothetical. It's about what the government could or might do, which implies that the government is *not* currently doing it, and we have no idea how likely it is to act in the future.

Comment: Conversely "If the government provides... children will..." could be used if the government was seriously considering doing this.

Comment: Can you Post some better examples, please?

'If the government provides free education…, children would gain access… for free, regardless from their parents’s income…' will never work in English, however obvious the sense seems.

'If I drink too much coffee, I can't sleep at night' works by itself.

'If we had a garden, we could have a cat' works by itself.

How can you compare 'If I drink too much coffee' to 'If we had a garden'?